# Linux tr command - operating on [:punct:] except from the character '

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to sort all the different words In a text file, using the following piped sequence:

cat story.txt | tr '(?!['])[[:punct:]]' "\n" | tr " " "\n" | tr "A-Z" "a-z" | sort | uniq

The problem is - I wish to use all white space and all punctuation marks EXCEPT FROM the mark ' as a separating character between lines. For that, I have tried a method called "Negative look ahead", but it doesn't seem to work... any ideas of how should I do it right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Convert spaces to newlines first
2. Convert `'` to a space
3. Convert your punctuation to newlines
4. Convert spaces *back* to `'`.

After step 2, the *only* spaces in your string will be ones standing in for `'`, not ones that should have been turned into newlines.

Something like

```
cat story.txt |
   tr ' ' '\n' |
   tr "'" ' ' |
   tr '[[:punct:]]' '\n' |  # [:punct:] already includes ?, !, etc
   tr ' ' "'" |
   tr "A-Z" "a-z" |
   sort | uniq
```